# Vitest TypeScript errors ts(2322) and ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, pinia, vitest

### **Background**

I'm trying to make my first unit tests to my Vue app using Vitest (with emphasis on *first*, which is the reason I don't really understand what I'm doing yet), and the tests *pass*, but I get TypeScript linter errors and I don't understand how to fix them.

**Test explanation**: I'm testing a function that receives two Pinia stores, gets information from one store, and based on that information it decides whether to call a function of the other store.

### First error - ts(2322) - "Type is missing the following properties"

Below is the relevant piece of code:

```
import { useStoreOne } from '@/stores/storeOne'
import { useStoreTwo } from '@/stores/storeTwo'
import { myFunction } from '@/functions'
import { describe, it, expect, vi, beforeEach } from 'vitest'

describe('myFunction', () => {
  let storeOne: ReturnType<typeof useStoreOne>
  let storeTwo: ReturnType<typeof useStoreTwo>

  beforeEach(() => {
    storeOne = {
      functionOne: vi.fn(),
      functionTwo: vi.fn(),
    }
    storeTwo = {
      functionThree: vi.fn(),
    }
  })

  // tests...
})
```

The error is on the assignments of storeOne and storeTwo inside the beforeEach.
I understand that the problem is that I missed some properties, but those stores have many properties, and I think that declaring them all is not the solution that I'm looking for.

- I tried using `Partial<ReturnType<typeof useStoreOne>>`, and it fixes the error, but it raises another error because `myFunction` gets the exact return type of `useStoreOne`, and not a partial return type.
- I have noticed that placing `as any` after the assignment solves this problem, but... I don't wanna use `any` because that misses the whole point of using TypeScript.

### Second error - ts(2339) - "Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist"

The second error appears on the tests themselves, which are described below:

```
  it('should not call functionThree', async () => {
    storeOne.functionOne.mockReturnValue(false)
    await myFunction(storeOne, storeTwo)
    expect(storeTwo.functionThree).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('should call functionThree', async () => {
    storeOne.functionOne.mockReturnValue(true)
    storeTwo.functionTwo.mockReturnValue(69)
    await myFunction(storeOne, storeTwo)
    expect(storeTwo.functionThree).toHaveBeenCalledWith(69)
  })
```

Here, the error appears on the `mockReturnValue` calls.
My linter recognizes the functions as... functions, but not as `vi.fn()`, i.e. they don't have properties such as `mockReturnValue`. Alongside with the first error, I believe that my mistake roots in the definitions of the stores in the `beforeEach`.

I tried all of changes mentioned above. I hereby remind that the tests pass, so I assume that it was properly written in its essence... but I leave some doubt that I should have written this completely different (e.g. I'm not even sure why I'm using `beforeEach`, and maybe that's the issue). I have also looked for answers on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find answers to my issue. ChatGPT was totally out of tune, and couldn't handle the fact that I'm using Vitest and not Jest.

Comment: I'd say RTFM at https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html , seems there are quite a bit of things that are builtin

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/blob/v2/packages/testing/src/testing.spec.ts is where that above link links for examples

Comment: I read TFM yesterday, it seemed to me quite shallow and I couldn't find my answers there.
One of the problems might be, again, TypeScript - TFM says that I can [mock getters](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#Mocking-getters), but when I tried to do as TFM says, I only got _"Cannot assign to 'myGetter' because it is a read-only property. ts(2540)"_.

Comment: Can you show the code? Did you use createTestingPinia()?

Comment: The code I showed in my question is the whole code (except for `myFunction`, which only calls some functions of the two stores).
I can share a link to my repo, but I think it's just gonna be more confusing.

To answer your other question - I tried using `const mockPinia = createTestingPinia()` as an alternative solution, and then initialize my stores by `const storeOne = useStoreOne(mockPinia)`; In that solution, not only that TypeScript didn't like my code, but also the tests failed, as if the mock didn't behave the way I wanted them to.

Comment: You are right actually https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1605 . Then a wrapper is a must

Comment: Oh wow, this is exactly the issue that I was talking about (but was explained better than I did), thank you!
How did you find that issue? Just a google search, or is there more to it?
And currently I'm going with the solution of `ts-expect-error` or `ts-ignore`, I just found it about an hour ago and it seems like a reasonable workaround for me.

Comment: I've googled "createTestingPinia typescript error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently I fell into the xy-problem: my issue wasn't what I thought my issue was.

This is the correct code:

```
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { useStoreOne } from '@/stores/storeOne'
import { useStoreTwo } from '@/stores/storeTwo'
import { myFunction } from '@/functions'
import { describe, it, expect, vi, beforeEach } from 'vitest'

describe('myFunction', () => {
  let storeOne: ReturnType<typeof useStoreOne>
  let storeTwo: ReturnType<typeof useStoreTwo>

  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia())
    storeOne = useStoreOne()
    storeTwo = useStoreTwo()
  })

  it('should not call functionThree', async () => {
    vi.spyOn(storeOne, 'functionOne', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(false)
    const functionThreeMock = vi.spyOn(storeTwo, 'functionThree')
    await myFunction(storeOne, storeTwo)
    expect(functionThreeMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

I had to understand what spies are and how to use them, as well as setting an active Pinia and initialize my stores with it instead of creating objects that *look like* my Pinia stores.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below wrapper to fix both of the above problems (but read the manual anyways)

```
import { vi, Mock } from 'vitest'
import { defineStore, StoreDefinition } from 'pinia'

let useStoreOne = defineStore('foo', {
  actions: {
    foo() { return 123 },
    bar() { return 123 },
  }
})

type MockStore<S> = {
  [K in keyof S
    as S[K] extends (...a: any[]) => any ? K : never
  ]?: S[K] extends (...a: infer A) => infer R ? Mock<A, R> : never
}
type Pick1<T, K> = Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, K>>

function mockStore<S extends StoreDefinition<any, any, any, any>, M extends MockStore<ReturnType<S>>>(
  useStore: S,
  mocks: M
): S & Required<Pick1<MockStore<ReturnType<S>>, keyof M>> {
  return mocks as any
}

let s = mockStore(useStoreOne, {
  bar: vi.fn()
})
// s is StoreOne & {bar: Mock}
```

Comment: This code reproduced ts(2322) again, and (excuse me for saying that, and that doesn't reduce the amount of my appreciation to your answers) I don't like this answer; It seems like a complex workaround that can probably be replaced with better workarounds provided by Vitest.

Nonetheless, it works (similar to my solution and unsimilar to the code on the manual); Just a reminder that the only issue here is TypeScript errors, not actual misbehavior of my code.

Comment: And with that being said - it is possible that the only bug is in the linter?
Is it possible that the linter just doesn't know that store getters can be overridden in a test environment, as described in the manual?

Comment: It's a bug in your typings - first you are trying to assign FakeStore to Store, and then you try to use Store as a FakeStore

Comment: If you want to use Store&FakeStore you need a wrapper like this, this one or the built-in one

Comment: If we break this down, I don't wanna use a real store, because I test only three functions of that store; i.e., if I add more logic to the stores, I'll have to add that logic to the tests' stores, and that doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

So we're left with the solution of FakeStore - which is what I'm trying to do.
I thought that by declaring `storeOne` with the return type of the real store, and assigning only the relevant code with `vi.fn()`, I created the desired FakeStore to test.
Why isn't that true? I'm not assigning a real store anywhere in my code...

Comment: Okay, I tried reproducing this error as a Minimal Reproduceable Example because I wanna be a good question asker, and it only seems that I was correct and that TypeScript just doesn't know that Pinia getters can be overridden in a test environment. The proof can be seen [here](https://shorturl.at/hsAWX): in this link you'll see the very code that's in the [manual](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#Mocking-getters), not a single change has been made - and still the same read-only error is being produced.

Comment: So you don't test the store itself, you test the functions using the store?

Comment: That's right, and that's what I wrote at the beginning: _"I'm testing a function that receives two Pinia stores, gets information from one store, and based on that information it decides whether to call a function of the other store."_
By the way, thank you for your patience and willing to dig in and help me with my issue! Much appreciated ^^

Comment: It seems that making a StoreMock type that is equivalent of Store but with mocks, based on the Store definition, is pretty straightforward. I guess I'll do this later today or tomorrow